# Why does my YouTube link on my Facebook profile redirecting to other account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, youtube-channel

I added my YouTube handle to my Facebook profile. But whenever I click that link/handle, it redirects to someone else's YouTube account. How am I gonna fix this?
P.S. I have tried adding "+" before the "@" but the problem persist. It still redirects to someone else's account.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.